# Is it possible to bindParam a Session variable?

Tags: php

What i want to achieve is when the user logs in the users id is saved as the session value, and when the logged in user selects date the products will display based on the date selected ONLY showing from that customer.

To confirm there are 2 issues here: 
1, How to save user id in Session?, 2, How do i bindParam sessionid?

Here is what i have in terms of code:

```
When user logs in:
    $_SESSION['customer_loggedin'] = $row['id']; 
THIS DOES NOT DISPLAY THE ID ON ROW?
```

When user selects the date, Ajax sends to:

```
session_start();
    include('db_config.php');
    $datepicker = $_POST['dateorderpicker'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE deliveryDate = ? AND cusomerId= ?"; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $datepicker, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    // HOW DO I BIND PARAM THE SESSION ID?

    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {   
        ?>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="content-boxes style-two top-column clearfix animated flipInY" style="opacity: 1;">
                <div class="content-boxes-text">
                    <h4><?php echo $row['itemName']; ?></h4>
                <img src="../wholesale/img/sourdough.jpg" class="img-reponsive">
                <p>Our best seller.  Full of flavour.</p>
                <form class="form-inline pull-right">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Qty</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="<?php echo $row['qty']; ?>">
                </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                </form>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
        <?php
    }
```

If there is any other information you need please feel free to ask. 
I am still learning so if you see something that is not right please let me know so i can better my php :)
Thanks

```
    if($login && $password)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE (code=:code OR phone=:phone OR businessName=:businessName OR email=:email) AND password=:password";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':code', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':phone', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':businessName', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':email', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $num = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        if($num > 0)
        {
        $_SESSION['customer_loggedin'] = $row['id'];
            header('location:order.php');
        }
        else{
            header('Location:index.php');
            $_SESSION['errmsg'] = 'Incorrect Login Details';
            die;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where you start session in your page?

Comment: I have session_start(); on both pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to save user id in Session?

You just have to start the session and set it like any other variable, just like you have it in the question. Just add `session_start()` before it:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['customer_loggedin'] = $row['id'];
```

> How do i bindParam sessionid?

Again, it's just like binding any other parameter. Once you call `session_start()` all previously set session variables are placed into the `$_SESSION` array.

```
$stmt->bindParam(2, $_SESSION['customer_loggedin'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: That's what i thought i should do however when i echo the session value it shows as 1. The session value should be 4 as in the table. I'll add my actual login script since this is probably the issue then.

Comment: The only way that the session array will have a different value is if you somehow set it somewhere else... or if it is not actually `1`, but you are type casting, for example, a string to an integer.

Comment: Well the problem now is after i add your script to mine i cannot start a session or login. I am using fetchColumn i dont know if this is the issue?

Comment: When using `fetchColumn`, you should be `SELECT`ing that column in your query, not `SELECT *`. In fact, unless you are going to be actually using all of the columns, it is good practice to explicitly say which columns you are selecting in your query. It avoids confusion and also lowers memory usage.

Comment: Also, what does `$row['id']` actually equal? If it equals 1 instead of 4, that's your problem.

Comment: I just changed the fetchcolumn to fetchAll, after verifying in the table, the field id has value of 4. However when i echoed it before i had a value of 1. The issue now is the fact that the: 
login script is not logging in, and thus the session is not starting? How should i be writing the login script? Is there something wrong with how its written? Please view the code at the end of my question. Thanks :)

Comment: It's kind of hard to debug your code without actually executing it. I don't see anything wrong with it, but I could be missing something. Add `error_reporting(-1);` to the top of your script and see if anything is printed to the browser or put in the error log. Try debugging your code using `var_dump($variable_to_check)` in strategic places. It could be that certain code blocks are not even being executed at all. Check for that too.

Answer (score 0):

you assign session variable into a variable bind it:-

```
 $row_id=$_SESSION['customer_loggedin'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE deliveryDate = ? AND cusomerId= ?"; 
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindParam(1, $datepicker, PDO::PARAM_STR);

 $sth->bindValue(2, $row_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->execute();
```